# Why are the X and Y index registers 8-bit?

Tags: 6502

I have been trying to get into 6502 programming, and something isn't adding up. If it has a 16-bit address space, why are the X and Y index registers 8-bit? Are they used in tandem, where X is the lower byte and Y is the higher byte of the address? If so how would that work?

Comment: No, X and Y can't be combined.  They are intended to be used as offsets from a base.  The only way to do 16-bit addressing is "indirect indexed", where the 16-bit base address is stored in the zero page.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, and could've been possible, but I think the answer is because the CPU deals in 8-bit values. If X & Y go to 16-bit then it makes sense that A would be too, and that's what happened in the 65C816.

Comment: Agreeing with @NickWestgate above: if `x` and `y` were defined as 16-bit, it would always take an extra cycle to calculate indexed addressing (rather than only sometimes, depending on the addressing mode). Furthermore the 6502 is best understood in comparison to the 6809 — the objective was to work sideways from there, better optimising functionality for cost. Chopping the index registers to 8 bit is a smart way to do that; you lose some functionality, you also lose a lot of cost.

Comment: The comparison should be to the 6800, not the 6809, though the 6502 does many things better than the former.  For many purposes, having two 8-bit index registers is much more useful than having one 16-bit index register like the 6800 does (the 6809 has two general-purpose 16-bit index registers).

Answer (score 3):

So I thought about and the answer is simpler than I thought. The index registers simply add to the base address (so `LDA $0200, X` will add X to 0x0200). If one wants to use a larger index register they can use indirect addressing. `:)`

Comment: Yes, the "zero" (or direct) page is kind of a register array if you consider the 6502 a primitive RISC design.